# Call parent function from child component to work on the parent

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

Is it possible to do this, when using Redux?

parent:

```
<ProductDetailsFooter 
  scrollToZero={() => this.scrollV && 
    this.scrollV.scrollTo({x: 0,y: 0,animated: true})
  }/>
```

child:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<*>, ownProps): any => ({
  scrollToZero: () => {
    ownProps.scrollToZero()
  }
})
```

Any idea how I can call ScrollToZero a parent function that has side effects on the parent from a child component? I'm using Redux so I can't just pass the function directly from the parent to the child as it doesn't register as a prop. I also can't just use a reducer because reducers only work on state, they don't scroll a page to a certain position.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why is redux involved here? If that `scrollToZero` function is just a side effect you want to happen, is there a reason you can't call `this.props.scrollToZero()` in the child component normally?

Comment: @kingdaro I just can't get the function to execute for some reason even without redux so I thought it might be because of redux overriding ownProps like it does with the state (you need to use ownProps in mapStateToProps).